# JAVA - Imprimir 2 tickets genereados en impresora termica y que los corte

Tags: java

Quisiera un poco de ayuda, es la primera vez que utilizare una impresora termica y no tengo idea de como hacerlo, lo que quiero que haga es que me imprima un archivo txt o en su caso un String que se genera con los datos que conforman un ticket (cantidad, precio, etc), quiero que lo imprima dos veces y que corte cada ticket para poder entregar uno al cliente y yo quedarme con otro

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que haz logrado para imprimir tu ticket? Muchas impresoras dentro de la configuración del driver especifican como cortar el papel o abrir el cajón ;)

Comment: revisa este [ejemplo](http://www.mets-blog.com/java-pos-thermal-printer-example/). Para imprimir la copia, deberías ejecutar print y cut dos veces.

Comment: @RubenHernandez abajo agregue el código, pensé que ya se había añadido cuando edite la publicación.

Comment: @Rcordoval mañana a primera hora pondré a prueba el ejemplo! Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la mayoria de impresoras POS cuando operan en modo texto existe una secuenca de caracteres por la cual se realiza el corte de papel

Estos caracteres suelen variar segun marca y modelo pero suelen estar en el manual técnico de la impresora.

Simplemente con enviar la combinación correcta de caracteres es suficiente
por ejemplo

```
w = new FileWriter(fichero);
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

// Message
builder.append("MOTEL OASIS\r\n");
builder.append("AV ESPINOZA 267, COL OBRERA\r\n");
builder.append("ENSENADA, B.C.\r\n");
builder.append("\r\n");
builder.append("DIA EXTRA\r\n);
builder.append("Fecha : ").append(fecha).append("       Hora: ").append(hora).append("\r\n");
builder.append(cantidad).append(" ").append(producto).append("            $").append(total).append("\r\n");
builder.append("\r\n");
builder.append("GRACIAS POR SU PREFERENCIA");
builder.append("\r\n");

// Paper Cut
char[] cutPaper = new char[] { 0x1d, 'i'};
builder.append(cutPaper);

bw.write(builder.toString());
bw.close();
```

En este caso envio el caracter de escape 27 (lo he puesto de forma que sea facil de ver) y luego el caracter "i"

Este ejemplo corresponde a las impresoras Bematec LR2000
http://bematechus.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/LR2000-Programming-Manual-v1.2.pdf

Para una EPSON T20 o similar (Todas las Epson TM) por ejemplo se deberian cambiar  los comandos de corte por:

```
byte[] cutPaper = new byte[] { 0x1d, 'V', 1 };
```

En definitiva deberas mirar los manuales de las impresoras compatibles.

Normalmente existen un conjunto de comandos para los diferentes tipos impresoras que permiten realizar estas operaciones.

Lo ideal seria tener una clase implementadora del modelo de impresora para usarlo con los comandos necesarios.

Asi mismo indicarte que estos comandos te pueden permitir dar mas vida al texto y otras funciones. Existen comandos de avance rapido (ejemplo mover el papel 10 o 100 lineas antes de cortar), Centrar el texto, alinear a la derecha,...

Una vez que tengas la clase implementadora puedes siempremente mandar el bloque de texto con la orden de corte dos veces para tener dos copias.

O si se paras los metodos llamar a una funcion print( texto) y luego cut() dos veces.

Comment: Para este caso no podría hacer que me lea todo el  txt con un ReadBuffer y mandarlo a la impresora con el correspondiente cut?

Solo con mandar un print y dos cut se imprime dos veces o tengo que mandar dos print y dos cut?

Comment: Podrias crear el fichero con el cut. Pero al ser caracteres de control. En parte no imprimibles cualquier problema del archivo (por ejemplo que alguien lo edite) podria hacer que ya no apareciera el cut. Por otro lado la impresora imprime lo que le digas . Segun el driver puedes madar un print y cut e indicarle que son dos copias al driver o mandar dos veces print y cut. El segundo caso es mas usado ya que normalmente en los tickets dobles no suelen ser 100% iguales (Como minimo uno pone "Copia para el cliente" y el otro "Copia para el establecimiento" por lo que suelen ser dos impresiones

Comment: que pena me a servido tu código pero me gustaría saber como obtengo la información de mi jtable para enviar a imprimir

Answer (score 0):

Este es el metodo mediante el cual genero mi ticket:

public void Dextra(String Hora,String Fecha, String Cantidad, String Total, String Producto){

```
    try
    {
        String carpeta = "C:\\MotelOasis\\Tickets\\";
        String archivo = "C:\\MotelOasis\\Tickets\\#LPT1.txt";
        File folder = new File(carpeta);
        folder.mkdirs();
        File fichero = new File(archivo);
        BufferedWriter bw;
        FileWriter fw;
        if(!fichero.exists())
        {   
            fichero.createNewFile();
            fw = new FileWriter(fichero);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("MOTEL OASIS"+"\r\n"
            +"AV ESPINOZA 267, COL OBRERA\r\n"
            +"ENSENADA, B.C.\r\n"
            +"\r\n"
            +"DIA EXTRA\r\n"
            +"Fecha : "+Fecha+"       Hora: "+Hora+"\r\n"
            +"\r\n"
            +Cantidad+" "+Producto+"            $"+Total+"\r\n"
            +"\r\n"
            +"GRACIAS POR SU PREFERENCIA");
            bw.close();
        }
        else if(fichero.exists())
        {
            int R=0;
            String archivo2 = "C:\\MotelOasis\\Tickets\\#LPT1.txt";
            String D2=null;
            FileReader f2 = null;
            try {
                f2 = new FileReader(archivo2);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Estado.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            BufferedReader b2 = new BufferedReader(f2);
            try {
                D2=b2.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Estado.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            fw = new FileWriter(fichero);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("MOTEL OASIS"+"\r\n"
            +"AV ESPINOZA 267, COL OBRERA\r\n"
            +"ENSENADA, B.C.\r\n"
            +"\r\n"
            +"DIA EXTRA\r\n"
            +"Fecha : "+Fecha+"       Hora: "+Hora+"\r\n"
            +"\r\n"
            +Cantidad+" "+Producto+"            $"+Total+"\r\n"
            +"\r\n"
            +"GRACIAS POR SU PREFERENCIA");
            bw.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Reportes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```